# AHK - mouseclick coordinates relative to app window

Tags: autohotkey

I was reading through AHK documentation but couldn't find one where it explains how to define the coordinates WITHIN a certain application window.

For example, I want to be able to minimize/maximize the ribbon in all microsoft office apps (top right corner). This should work reliably no matter whether the window is maximized or not, and the mouse cursor should not shift (or at least it should shift back) while doing so.

Any idea how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want coordinates to be relative to the active window, you need to use the [`CoordMode`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm) command at the top of your script.  The second parameter specifies the coordinate mode will be for mouse coordinates.  The third parameter you can specify either `Screen` or `Relative`.  Relative is what you are looking for.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative
```